# Server Error in '/' Application. Requested URL not correct

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

when publishing my ASP.Net WebForm application I am getting the following error:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /
```

I need the requested URL to be `/welcome.html`

I have tried the following:

1. Went into Azure Portal and modified default documents to Welcome.HTML
2. Changed the Web settings in my project to navigate to a specific page "Welcome.HTML"
3. Changed my RouteConfig.cs file to the following

```
                name: "Default",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );
```

**Also to note I can direct to the welcome.html page directly no issue by modifying the url i.e., url.com/welcome.html**

Any help here would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Add under the configuration node of the Web.config file

```
<system.Webserver>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <add value="welcome.html" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.Webserver>
```

Make sure `welcome.html` is in the root directory